# Global variable not saving updated value

Tags: python-3.x

I have a global variable `foo`. I am using a function to add a number (which is sent as parameter to the function) to `foo`. The first time I call this function, it runs fine, but the second time I run this, it only gives me the sum of initial value of `foo` and the number passed as parameter. I am new to python and following is my code.

```
foo = 5
def add_number_to_foo(num):
    global foo
    return foo + num

add_number_to_foo(5)  # returns 10 which is fine

add_number_to_foo(6)  # returns 11, I should have got 16
```

I am a newbie in python, please excuse me if the question is ignorant. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that whatever you are returning is not set back to the variable `foo`. Following code should fix your problem:

```
foo = 5
def add_number_to_foo(num):
    global foo
    return foo + num

foo = add_number_to_foo(5)  # returns 10 which is fine
print(foo)  # prints 10
foo = add_number_to_foo(6)  # returns 11, I should have got 16
print(foo)  # prints 16
```

Comment: `foo + num` by itself won't assign it to the variable `foo` since `foo` is global?

Comment: @code_noob no it won't because, there is nothing to assign it to on the left

Answer (score 1):

I did the following that worked. Based on @learner's comment.

```
foo = 5
def add_number_to_foo(num):
    global foo
    foo = foo + num
    return foo

add_number_to_foo(5)  # returns 10
add_number_to_foo(6)  # returns 16
```

Since now I have assigned the variable to `foo` it works perfectly fine.